# small blue square whenever the app loads after closing and opening again

Tags: flutter

This is the image of my app whenever it loads after closing and re-opening it. I have tried searching or debugging it on my `main.dart` file which is the first thing that loads whenever I run the app.
this is my `main.dart` file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:todo_app/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:todo_app/routes/router.dart';
import 'package:todo_app/services/auth_checker.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await dotenv.load(
    fileName: '.env',
  );
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // ** This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Sizer(
      builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
        return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'To Do App',
            theme: ThemeData.light(),
            onGenerateRoute: RouteManager.generateRoute,
            initialRoute: '/checkAuthentication',
            home: const AuthenticationChecker());
      },
    );
  }
}
```

so after running the app it just check if the user is authenticated if not it will go to `LoginScreen` if yes it will redirect to `HomePageScreen` however, I do not know why is there a small blue square whenever it loads first.

This is running on emulator and I've tried running it on a real device however the result is still the same.
[image: This is the image of my app whenever it loads after closing and re-opening it]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

1. Getting rid of redundant StreamBuilders (reduces loading time)
2. Replacing CircularProgressIndicators with Container

these two solved the problem for me.